# Botão com link para um site

Tags: swift, xcode

Será que poderiam me ajudar a fazer um botão com um link para um site?
É uma aplicação para iPhone e queria que ao carregar num botão, abrisse o site no Safari(por exemplo).

Comment: como faço? eu fiz o butao mas nao sei o que fazer agora

Comment: E o que pretende fazer? Qual comportamento espera que tenha esse botão? Você pode [edit] a sua pergunta e incluir mais informações. A propósito, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e entenda melhor como o StackOverflow funciona, bem vindo.

Comment: Já fiz a edicão da minha questão

Comment: Você mencionou que já fez o botão, poderia editar a sua pergunta e incluir o código do botão nela?

Comment: o botao que eu fiz foi só criar um botao mais nada, não fiz código nenhum

Comment: Dá uma olhada [**neste link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25477547/3624981) @BrunoGonçalves , E [**neste link também**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26938495/3624981)

Comment: como crio uma IBAction?

Answer (score -1):

A função para isto é a `openURL`, um exemplo:

```
@IBAction func WebLink(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://...") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Já resolvi obrigado (:

Comment: Se você já resolveu por favor edite sua pergunta ou crie uma resposta dizendo como foi que resolveu o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra abordagem seria utilizar a `SFSafariViewController`, ela abre o safari sem sair do seu aplicativo. Isso melhora bastante a usabilidade do App.

Primeiro, na sua ViewController, importe o `SafariServices`. E utilize a `SFSafariViewController` da seguinte forma:

```swift
if let url = URL(string: "http://...") {
    let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariViewController, animated: true)
}
```